# Implementing pure virtual functions from class template - parameter types

Tags: c++, templates, types, covariance, virtual-functions

I want to create an abstract class template, forcing all instances to implement a `doStuff` function using a pure virtual function.

I have the following template:

```
template<class T>
class X
{
    public:
        X() {};
        virtual ~X() {};
        virtual X<T>& doStuff(X<T>& x) = 0;
};
```

And an instance with T= int:

```
class Y : public X<int>
{
    public:
        Y();
        virtual ~Y();
        Y& doStuff(Y& x) {
            Y res;
            Y& res2 = res;
            return res2;
        }
};
```

I get the error message:

> `In member function ‘Y& Y::doStuff(Y&)’: cannot declare variable ‘res’ to be of abstract type ‘Y’ because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘Y’: X<T>& X<T>::doStuff(X<T>&) [with T = int]`

If I change the type of the argument to `doStuff` in `Y`, everything is fine:

```
class Y : public X<int>
 {
    public:
        Y();
        virtual ~Y();
        Y& doStuff(X<int>& x) {
            Y res;
            Y& res2 = res;
            return res2;
        }
};
```

Why can the parameter not be a reference to a `Y` object when `Y` implements X?

The return value of `Y&` does not create a similar error message.

Maybe I am using the wrong approach to achieve what I want - feel free to let me know.

Comment: Unrelated: you are returning a reference to a local variable, hence a *dangling reference*

Comment: That is true. I just wanted the sample to compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why can the parameter not be a reference to a Y object when Y implements X?

Because you have to give the exact signature as it was declared in the pure virtual function of the base.

That's why

```
class Y : public X<int> {
    // ...
    X<int>& doStuff(X<int>& x) override;
};
```

works.

See the working [Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f1b0d2d3569f82c4).

---

<sub>Not to mention that returning a reference to a local variable is undefined behavior.</sub>

Comment: Long live the `override` keyword :)

Comment: @vsoftco Yeah!!

Answer (score 3):

By setting `Y&` as the parameter you change the signature of `doStuff` and therefore `res` is abstract.

`X<int>&` is not `Y&` even though `Y` inherits `X`.

Comment: @User That's because of [*covariant return types*](http://www.lwithers.me.uk/articles/covariant.html). A virtual function is allowed to return a pointer or reference to a derived while still being considered an override.

Comment: Okay - makes sense. But how am I supposed to implement what I want then? Just use X<int> instead of Y and that's it?

Comment: @User _"Just use X<int> instead of Y and that's it?"_ Merely, yes.